Unable to get heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors for PLM "between" model
I am presently running a regression on a balanced panel dataset, where I observe +1000 individuals over a T=10 time period. Given that individual specific independent variables remain constant over time, but differ accross the individuals, I decided to choose the between model of plm.
However, when trying to compute heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors I receive the following error:
> coeftest(plm_between, vcov = vcovHC(plm_between, type = "HC2"))    
Error in vcovG.plm(x, type = type, cluster = cluster, l = 0, inner = inner,  : 
Model has to be either "random", "within", "pooling", or "fd" model

I assume the between estimator is not supported, but what can I use instead to get be robust standart errors? When choosing within or pooling the robust errors are indeed calculated - though, that is not the desired model... Would there be an alternative method in getting robust SE's?
Questioning, if I even need the between method - could I achieve the same analysis using lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + factor(group_id) + factor(year)?
Thank you very much!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
